# Take only the first five rows of a long list separated by empty lines (C++)

Tags: c++, list, ifstream

I am a bit stuck on what I want to do with my C++ code:

```
int main() {
char bid_price[512];
char bid_volume[512];
char ask_price[512];
char ask_volume[512];

const int MAX_LEN = 512;
ifstream in_stream;
in_stream.open("test.txt");

char current_string[MAX_LEN];

if (!in_stream) {
    cout << "Could not open data.txt" << endl;
    return false;
}

for (int i=0; i<150 && 
        (in_stream.getline(current_string,MAX_LEN) && current_string.length()==0); i++) {
    in_stream.getline(current_string, MAX_LEN);
    get_word(current_string, 1, bid_price);
    cout << "First word is: " << bid_price << endl;
    get_word(current_string, 2, bid_volume);
    cout << "Second word is: " << bid_volume << endl;
    get_word(current_string, 4, ask_price);
    cout << "Third word is: " << ask_price << endl;
    get_word(current_string, 5, ask_volume);
    cout << "Fourth word is: " << ask_volume << endl;
}

in_stream.close();

return 0;
```

}

What I would like to do is to take only the first five rows of such a list in a txt file such as the following:

1. 383.80000 | 0.014 | 1461142717 || 383.67000 | 5.141 | 1461142798
2. 383.61100 | 0.010 | 1461134871 || 383.60000 | 9.076 | 1461142798
3. 383.51100 | 0.010 | 1461136836 || 383.46100 | 0.400 | 1461142794
4. 383.41100 | 0.010 | 1461129820 || 383.35000 | 7.740 | 1461142798
5. 383.31100 | 0.010 | 1461129821 || 383.30000 | 0.014 | 1461142637
6. 383.21100 | 0.010 | 1461138430 || 383.20000 | 2.000 | 1461142787
7. 383.16100 | 9.089 | 1461142763 || 383.11100 | 0.010 | 1461134135
8. "EMPTY LINE"
9. 383.01100 | 8.573 | 1461138900 || 383.00000 | 50.037 | 1461142501
10. 382.98300 | 5.000 | 1461135929 || 382.97000 | 0.150 | 1461142461
11. 382.93400 | 3.476 | 1461138822 || 382.91100 | 0.010 | 1461128348
12. 382.81900 | 8.762 | 1461136840 || 382.81100 | 0.010 | 1461128350
13. 382.80000 | 0.014 | 1461141922 || 382.71100 | 0.010 | 1461142621
14. 382.68000 | 15.936 | 1461142797 || 382.67000 | 2.000 | 1461141655
15. 382.66900 | 4.305 | 1461130920 || 382.61100 | 0.010 | 1461136076

In this case I'd take only the rows number 1,2,3,4,5 and 9,10,11,12,13
Note: Nevermind the function `get_word`, it works very well.

Comment: Also search for close matches by using "stackoverflow c++ read file struct" and "stackoverflow read file comma separated".

Comment: Is it obvious, that to read the first 5 lines you would change the comparison in your `for` loop to 5?

Comment: Pleaae, please don't use a char array to represent strings in c++. Whenever possibleUse use `std::string` instead. And I also wouldn't use `endl` unless you want to explicitly flush the console output after each line.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to skip blank lines.  A lot easier than worrying how many text lines to read:

```
std::string text_line;
while (getline(in, text_line))
{
  // If text line is blank, skip it
  if (text_line.empty())
  {
    continue;
  }

  // Otherwise process the text line.
  // ...
}
```

I highly recommend you add in some more error detection for lines that don't meet the format.

**Edit 1: Skipping specific lines**
To skip specific lines, you will need to have a line counter and a container of lines to skip.

```
const unsigned int lines_to_skip[] = {8, 24, 25, 26, 101, 113, 125};
const unsigned int skip_list_size = sizeof(lines_to_skip) / sizeof(lines_to_skip[0]);
std::string text_line;
unsigned int line_counter = 0;
unsigned int skip_index = 0;
//...
while (getline(in, text_line))
{
  ++line_counter;
  if (skip_index < skip_list_size)
  {
    if (line_counter == lines_to_skip[skip_index])
    {
      ++skip_index;
      continue;
    }
  }
  // Perform other validations
  // ...

  // Process the text line.
}
```

Skipping blank and invalid lines is a lot more efficient than skipping lines by line number.

Comment: I have an issue I dont understand, which is: error: request for member ‘empty’ in ‘current_string’, which is of non-class type ‘char [512]’
   if (current_string.empty()) {

Answer (score 0):

You want to read 5 lines and disregard empty lines.

So, one easy way to do it would be to first remove all empty lines from your dataset and then subsequently just grab the top 5 ones.

An alternative would be to keep track of how many lines you've successfully read and while that variable is less than 5, read one more. Then only increase the counter when you read a non-blank line and don't increment it when you skip a blank one. Continue until the counter is 5 or you run out of lines to read.

Comment: I'd be happy to do the first and easy way. However, I'm not sure whether it's going to work as I need to grab the first five rows after the empty line